# Error running systrace tool in ADB using a Jelly Bean 4.1 emulator on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean, systrace

How can I run `systrace` to show its html output? After watching the Google I/O 2012 talk ["For Butter or Worse"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Q8m9sHdyXnE#t=31m15s) I am having trouble getting `systrace` to work on Windows 7 using the emulator running Jelly Bean 4.1.

I did the following:

1. Installed Python 2.7, and added the install folder to my PATH
2. Ran the following: `C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace>python systrace.py` (with older SDKs: `C:\android-sdk\tools\systrace>python systrace.py`)

But I get the following error in cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "systrace.py", line 212, in <module>
    main()
  File "systrace.py", line 124, in main
    ready = select.select([adb.stdout, adb.stderr], [], [adb.stdout, adb.stderr])
select.error: (10093, 'Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed')
```

Note:

- I have enabled traces in the emulator: `Settings > Developer Options > Enable traces`
- I have also tried with Python 3.2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The systrace python script uses the select() system call, and that doesn't work on Windows.
The [latest preview](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel) (ADT21 rc9) of the Android SDK tools include support for collecting system trace from within the monitor tool.

Launch monitor as:

```
./tools/monitor &
```

Click on a device, and at the top right of the device panel, you should have an toolbar itemn that allows you to collect system trace.

Comment: You can also directly switch to DDMS view from within Eclipse.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky that means to open a executable in linux independent from the current shell. you can omit that in windows

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue. It appears that systrace.py attempts to use select.select() with file descriptors which, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#select.select), is not supported on Windows.

I ended up running the tool from a Linux VM.

Comment: Can you post detailed instructions on what Linux Vm tool you used? :) I'm sure if you did you will get the answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse for your development then you can use the built in Systrace utility as well as outlined @ http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html . Its the easiest way I found for collecting traces.