# Android jelly bean 4.1 systrace tool

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, systrace

How to use systrace tool in android jelly bean 4.1 to work on windows 7 32-bit OS.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What is the specific problem you're facing? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300773/error-running-systrace-tool-in-adb-using-a-jelly-bean-4-1-emulator-on-windows-7

Comment: see just am asking how to use that tool.what is vague in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the recently published Systrace documentation on the developer.android.com site:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html
- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html

That should get you started.