# Systrace gives no such option error for --set-tags

Tags: android, systrace

I'm following the instructions here to use systrace for my application but I keep getting the following error whenever I try to set the tags for systrace:

```
systrace.py: error: no such option: --set-tags
```

This seems to be a rather new issue that just cropped up for me yesterday. Does anyone know what's up? It seems to only be an issue for when I'm trying to systrace on a device running 4.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `--set-tags` option for 4.3.  The way systrace works changed significantly, and the documentation hasn't yet been updated.  (**Edit:** it has been updated for 4.3)

The `systrace.py` script checks the device version, and forwards the commands to `systrace-legacy.py` for pre-4.3 devices.  That's why the old command still works for older devices.

An example for a 4.3 device would be:

```
python systrace.py gfx view sched dalvik
```

That is, you just list the tags you want as arguments to the command that starts the tracing.

I have an example (which also shows off the new app-defined tag feature) [here](http://bigflake.com/systrace/).

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome. Thanks for explaining. Hopefully the documentation gets updated soon.

Comment: @fadden Did you have trouble getting the `gfx` to work? For some reason my device refuses to output information related to `gfx` and `view` and the result is an empty `trace.html` file... however, it seems to work properly when I specify `cpu`. Is there some extra setting I need to enable in order to get `gfx` info to be generated?

Comment: Nope.  `gfx` and `view` should be easy -- no root required -- so I'm surprised they're being difficult.  The mechanism works by setting `debug.atrace.tags.enableflags` to an integer value, broadcasting a "hey everybody, re-read the flags" through Binder IPC, running the trace, and then resetting enableflags to 0.  If the flags don't get set or the apps+surfaceflinger don't see the broadcast, they might not know to log data for those tags.  (cf. frameworks/native/cmds/atrace/atrace.cpp in the 4.3 sources.)  The way this is implemented changed quite a bit in 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "python systrace.py gfx view sched dalvik" works, I think google need to update the help info of systrace.py.

However, in Android 4.3, you can also use "Capture system wide trace using Android systrace" in DDMS perspective window in eclipse bundled in latest android sdk. Just like the post [here](http://www.cppblog.com/wythern/archive/2013/09/09/203109.html).

Comment: Well you are right but in windows you will get [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11300773/995926).