# Android systrace errno 8

Tags: android, sdk, systrace

I have Win7 PC, latest android sdk and Python 2.7 and trying to start systrace.
I start script from "\android-sdks\platform-tools\systrace\"
After commsnd "python systrace.py" i recieve error:
OSError: [errno 8] Exec format error

What can this be? adb and python are correctly installed and working good.

Comment: Do you have systrace-legacy.py in that same directory?  Can you run it without getting the errno 8?  (systrace.py will run that if your device is pre-Android 4.3.)

Comment: @fadden You should include this as an actual answer so that it can be marked correct.

Comment: I have same errors, when using systrace from command line. But i have found, that Eclipse SDK has DDMS panel, whare i acan get log from device, connected to my pc, with out using command line. It is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windows doesn't support running systrace from command line.
please check the following questions

[Error running systrace tool in ADB using a Jelly Bean 4.1 emulator on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300773/error-running-systrace-tool-in-adb-using-a-jelly-bean-4-1-emulator-on-windows-7)

[Systrace for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows)