# Running systrace gives "preexec_fn is not supported on Windows" error

Tags: android, python, systrace

I'm trying to use Android's Systrace feature as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace-commandline.html#options-4.3) but when I run the command line described in the above links, it gives me this error :

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 664, in __init__
raise ValueError("preexec_fn is not supported on Windows "
ValueError: preexec_fn is not supported on Windows platforms
```

The command line described above is :

```
python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm
```

I'm not a python dev so I don't have any clue about it and google doesn't help me a lot, any idea?

-- I'm running on a windows 10 computer.

Comment: Have you found a soloution? I have got the same issue :(

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried to comment the code that was throwing the exception but as expected this gives some other errors. As I said I'm not a python dev and I don't have the time to learn about it so I'm quite stuck with this error.

Comment: It means systrace uses a feature that Windows does not have. Try submitting them a bug report.

Comment: did you try the latest platform tools?

Comment: @bladefury Yes I tried with the latest platform tools.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz I'll submit a bug report and come back here if I got any news, thank's for the advice.

Comment: I am still seeing this error.  Did they fix this issue already?

Comment: refer the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300773/error-running-systrace-tool-in-adb-using-a-jelly-bean-4-1-emulator-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

Even I faced same issue. Replace the catapult folder in your SDK's platform-tools/systrace location with the catapult folder downloaded from below link.

https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult