# Android systrace command error

Tags: android, systrace

I wanted to use the systrace.py command to generate trace.html file, i used the command like this:

> systrace.py -t 5 -o trace.html

then i got the error:

> ValueError: preexec_fn is not supported on Windows platforms

---

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300773/error-running-systrace-tool-in-adb-using-a-jelly-bean-4-1-emulator-on-windows-7

Comment: @DatNguyen That not works for me,i have tried the solutions described in link before. thank u.